# Yellow under line for chewiecontroller

Tags: flutter, video

I have application which use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) and [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie)

This is my source code, it plays the given url in `widget.video`

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/vid/' + widget.video)
  ..initialize().then((_) {
    _controller.play();
    setState(() {});    
});
_chewieController = ChewieController(
  videoPlayerController: _controller,
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  autoPlay: true,
  looping: false,
);
```

However there comes some yellow underline.

[image]

How can I remove this line???

Or Can I customize here??

These are my all code of page.

```
class AnimePage extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimePage({Key key, this.title,this.video}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final String video;

  @override
  _AnimePageState createState() => _AnimePageState();
}

class _AnimePageState extends State<AnimePage> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //print(widget.video);
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/vid/' + widget.video)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _controller.play();
        setState(() {});    
    });
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _controller,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: false,
    );   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        return 
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child:
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child:
                        Chewie(controller: _chewieController,)
                  )
              ]),),
              TabBar()
            ]
          );
      }
       
       });
  }
```

Comment: You will need to place those widgets in a `Scaffold` I guess. Are they in a `Scaffold` widget already ?

Comment: I don't use `Scaffold` just using `Widget`. adding my source code.

Comment: you can try wrapping you Chewie with Material

Comment: Wrap the `OrientationBuilder` with a `Scaffold` ?

Comment: I wrap `OrientationBuilder` with `Scaffold` it works!!!. Normally I don't use `Scaffold` Now I need to understand `Scaffold` more